# SQL Enter parameter value

Tags: sql, ms-access

Im new to sql, Im writing a query to display the project numbers that have employees assigned to them.

```
SELECT PROJ_NUM
FROM project
WHERE EMP_NUM IS NOT null;
```

When i run the query I get asked to enter the parameter value for EMP_NUM. Why am i getting asked this?

Comment: What program are you using to run this SQL?

Comment: running it on ms access

Comment: OK, I've tagged your question with `ms-access`; you should do that next time so the right people see it sooner.

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/access-help/why-does-access-want-me-to-enter-a-parameter-value-HA010274377.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ordinarily that would suggest a spelling error, and that your `project` table doesn't include a field named `EMP_NUM`.  However, if you've already confirmed that field does exist, perhaps the problem is due to the table name, `project`, which is a [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#P).

In that case, try your query like this ...

```
SELECT p.PROJ_NUM
FROM [project] AS p
WHERE p.EMP_NUM IS NOT null;
```

**Postmortem**:  OP confirmed `EMP_NUM` does not exist in the `project` table.  That is the reason the db engine interpreted it to be a parameter.  The situation was confusing because with `project` open in Datasheet View, `EMP_NUM` was displayed in a subdatasheet of a related table.  By examining his database relationships, OP was able to determine which table includes `EMP_NUM` and then `INNER JOIN` that table to `project` in his query.

Comment: I tried using p but i still get prompted. Does it matter if EMP_NUM is in a drop down(+ - sign) from PROJ_NUM?

Comment: Could the `+/-` indicator be for a subdatasheet of a related table?  If so, `EMP_NUM` may not exist in `Project` but in the related table instead.

Comment: Please open the `project` table in Design View and tell us whether or not it includes a field named `EMP_NUM`.

Comment: It doesnt but in the datasheet view i see PROJ_NUM one of them being 15 and to the left of 15 there is a plus sign that expands when I click it when i click the plus sign it expands under PROJ_NUM to reveal EMP_NUM and a couple other fields.

Comment: Track down which table includes `EMP_NUM` and `INNER JOIN` that table to `project`.  Do that in the query designer because it will help you set up the join correctly.  Examine your database relationships (Database Tools -> Relationships) to find out which tables are related to `project`.  One of those will include the `EMP_NUM` field.